# Can't a thread can be "paused" in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

i wrote a program to try threads in C but it's strange

it doesn't get stuck in whiles (like `while (1){}`)

i tried to pause my program with a getchar, with a scanf, with a while(1), it doesn't stop, why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void    *monthread(void *arg)
{
    char c;
    printf("Thread is in execution\n"); // this line is executed ! why not the others ?
    c = getchar();
    scanf(&c);
    while(1)
    {
        c = 'e';
    }

    (void) arg; // and can someone explain me this line please ? i was reading a tutorial
    pthread_exit(NULL); // and it says to add this but why ? what does it do  ?  thanks
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    pthread_t thread_h;

    printf("Thread creation in 3 2 1\n");

    if(pthread_create(&thread_h, NULL, monthread, NULL) == -1){
        perror("pthread_create");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    i = getchar();
    printf("thread created\n");
    /*while (1){
      i = 0;
      }*/
}
```

fanks !

Comment: How would you know whether the thread was "stopped"?

Comment: `c = getchar(); scanf(&c);` are you sure?

Comment: uhm yes i mean like, just stopping the program, is it impossible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between the OS and a multi-threaded program is always guided by the lifetime of the main thread. When the main thread ends, all subtended threads are killed by the OS.

In your case, the main thread runs to its end without waiting for the split-off thread - Thus the split-off thread is silently killed. This can even happen before the subtended thread had a chance to *do anything*. If you want your subtended thread to "stay alive", you need to *wait* for it in the main thread using `pthread_join()`.

BTW: Busy waiting like you do in your program is normally no good method to keep a thread alive. It will hog the CPU without doing anything.